# Is there a way to call a function once and use the return value twice inside an array value?

Tags: javascript

I have a logic problem and I'm not sure if JavaScript offers a special way to solve this.  In the simplified test code below I use a function to create a random number and I place it into an array value twice.  I  need to use the identical random number in two places but obviously if I call `randomNumber()` twice I get two different return values.  I know I can store the return value in a variable and call that variable multiple times.  But does JavaScript offer  any other approach for a problem like this?

```js
"use strict";

let myArray = [
    `Use a random number once here, ${randomNumber()}, and the same value again here ${randomNumber()}.`
];

function randomNumber() {
  return Math.random() * 10;
}

document.querySelector('.output').textContent = myArray[0];
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: you may read about closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the array element as an IIFE that returns the desired string, passing in the (single) result of `randomNumber()`:

```js
"use strict";

let myArray = [
    ((rnd) => `Use a random number once here, ${rnd}, and the same value again here ${rnd}.`)(randomNumber())
];

function randomNumber() {
  return Math.random() * 10;
}

document.querySelector('.output').textContent = myArray[0];
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)...

```
function *randomize(num = Math.random() * 10) {
  for (;;) yield num
}

let myNum = randomize(),
  myArray = [
    `Use a random number once here, ${myNum.next().value}, and the same value again here ${myNum.next().value}.`
  ];
```